# CSS - how to make dynamic padding of children within a container

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I am trying to make dynamic padding within a container and are having some trouble with that.

If I for example have this html

```
<div class="sections-container">
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
</div>
```

and this styling

```
.sections-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 2.4rem;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

then the padding in the container is hardcoded to be 24px. You can see it at this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yw8xyp?file=style.css.

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. When the container gets larger, then the padding of the container should get bigger to a maks padding of 100px.
2. When the container gets smaller, then the padding of the container should get smaller to minimum padding of 10px.

So when the container hit a specific size - then the padding should change dynamically - increase or decrease dependinding on the container size. I am trying to do this only using CSS - if that is even possible :D

Does someone know how to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Read up on flex. Especially the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property.

Comment: you can also use media queries in CSS.

Comment: use twitter bootrap.

Comment: Flex is the best solution here in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve adaptive padding, using a variable for the width like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u26fhc?embed=1&file=style.css

For min and max you need media queries

Comment: okay, cool. I am quite new to css and didnt know that variables existed. This is close to how i wanted it to work - i'll look into media queries. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want padding in all 4 sides. 
use display flex

```
    .sections-container {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 80%;
      height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .section {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 70%;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is define break points and set paddings accordingly.